# Cannot detect if child process has been killed

Tags: c++

I been reading a countless time on stackoverflow that to determine if a process is running, one should use kill(pid,0) but I cant make it work

here is my code, , it cannot detect when the child process has been killed and I dont understand why

(sorry for the ident, but hte code escaping on stackoverflow is just a pain for long pieces of codes)

```
#include <sys/signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main()
{
int pid = fork();

if (pid < 0)
{
    printf("Forking failed\n");
} 
else if (pid == 0) // child process
{ 
    do
    {
        printf("child process\n");  
        sleep(1);
    }while(1);
    //execvp("ls", NULL); //launches the application
} 
else //parent process
{ 
    printf("parent process\n");
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        if(i==5)
            kill(pid,SIGTERM); //kills the child process
        if(kill(pid, 0) == 0)
            printf("process child %d is runnig\n",pid);
        else if(kill(pid, 0) == -1)
        {
            switch(errno)
            {
                case ESRCH: printf("process child %d is not runnig\n",pid); break;
                case EPERM: printf("process child %d cannot be killed\n",pid); break;
                default: printf("%s\n",strerror(errno));    break;
            }
        }

        sleep(1); 
    }

} 
}
```

here is the output

```
parent process
process child 1918 is runnig
child process
process child 1918 is runnig
child process
process child 1918 is runnig
child process
process child 1918 is runnig
child process
process child 1918 is runnig
child process
process child 1918 is runnig
process child 1918 is runnig
process child 1918 is runnig
process child 1918 is runnig
process child 1918 is runnig
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alright I finaly figured it out

```
kill(pid,SIGTERM); //kills the child process
do
    {
       pid = waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG);
   if(pid == 0)
      sleep(1);
}while(pid<=0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Until the killed child process gets reaped by `wait()`, its `PID` is still valid, and `kill(pid, 0);` will succeed, since the `PID` exists. Your code attempts to `kill()` the child process, but fails to `wait()` for it.

Note that even in the best case, `kill(pid, 0);` is not reliable. With only 32766 different PIDs, it doesn't take long before process IDs get recycled.

Comment: It's reliable for your own children because presumably you know their PIDs and whether you've `wait()`ed for them yet.

Comment: @melpomene - as soon as wait() returns, the pid can not be reassigned to another process.

Comment: besides there is a waitpid function , should I use it instead ?

Comment: In this situation, it doesn't matter. In other situations, maybe. Why don't you read the description of wait() and waitpid(), and figure it out yourself.

Comment: well I tried kill(pid,SIGTERM); waitpid(pid,NULL,WNOHANG); and still the same issue

Comment: Who told you to use WNOHANG?